# use ng-options or ng-repeat in select?

Tags: angularjs

I want use `select` in angularjs. 
I have a json that every element have 2 part: `name` and `value`. I want show `name` in dropdown and when user select one of theme, `value` is copy to `ng-model`.

```
$scope.list = [{name:"element1",value:10},{name:"element2",value:20},{name:"element3",value:30}];
```

For this I have 2 way to use select:

1. `ng-options`:

I use `ng-options` like below:

```
<select ng-model="model.test" ng-options="element.name for element in list"></select>
```

It's work correctly, but when I select each of element, I want just `value` of element is copy to ng-model, but a json is copy to ng-model, like below:

```
$scope.model.test = {name:"element1",value:1}
```

I can resolve this problem in angular controller, but I want find a better way that resolve this problem.

For resolove this problem, I use second way:

2.use `ng-repeat` in `options`:

```
    <select ng-model="model.test">
      <option ng-repeat="element in list" value="{{element.value}}">{{element.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

In second way, just value is copy to ng-model, but as a string type:

```
$scope.model.test = "10";
```

I use below code, but all of them return a string value to model.

```
<option ng-repeat="element in list" value={{element.value}}>{{element.name}}</option>
<option ng-repeat="element in list" value="{{element.value}}|number:0">{{element.name}}</option>
<option ng-repeat="element in list" value={{element.value}}|number:0>{{element.name}}</option>
```

How can fix this problem?

Comment: `ng-options="element.value as element.name for element in list"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can resolve it with ng-options as well

```
      ng-options="element.value as element.name for element in list"
```

please read [this blog](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs) to understand more about ng-options.

Also another advantage of ng-options is, it binds the object as opposed to json string in case you want to attach the selected object to ng-model.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this :

```
 <select ng-model="model.test" ng-options="element.value element.name for element in list"></select>
```

btw, if you may have hundreds of records into your list, you should create your own directive, where you would manipulate your DOM with a simple javascript for loop

ng-repeat will be slow to be rendered,
ng-options adds every record into $watch.

Comment: with 1.3 you can control if you dont want to add every record to $watch like `in ::list`